Импортируемый пакет не имеет .mod файла. Как использовать этот пакет?
У меня go23
Я оформляю свои программы в виде go-модуля.
Однако, в одной из моих программ, потребовалось импортировать пакет github.com/lxn/walk.
Этот пакет не имеет go.mod файла так как был написан до введения модулей в golang.
Обычный go get и go get -u его скачивают, но добавить в мой проект не дают.
Как я могу использовать этот пакет в своем проекте? Как правильно его испортировать?


когда пытаюсь собрать именно пример из README то получаю
package github.com/udonetsm/test
        imports github.com/lxn/walk: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/active/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lxn/walk@v0.0.0-20210112085537-c389da54e794

В то время как сожержимое  /home/active/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lxn/walk@v0.0.0-20210112085537-c389da54e794 на первом скриншоте

инструкции из README не помогают? Вообще, пакеты (то, что было до модулей, и то, чем, похоже, является эта библиотека) импортируются в файл, в отличие от модулей, которые импортируются в .mod. Я бы попробовал просто сбросить пакет в директорию проекта и записать в main'е import "<module_name>/walk"

Опишите подробнее, что означает "добавить в мой проект не дают". Я попробовал собрать пример из REAME - пример собрался и запустился.  go get отработал успешно, в моём go.mod появились записи github.com/lxn/walk v0.0.0-20210112085537-c389da54e794 // indirect и github.com/lxn/win v0.0.0-20210218163916-a377121e959e // indirect, go build собрал бинарник. Что именно происходит у вас?

@PakUula добавил информацию в вопрос.

@Quester вы собираете в Windows или Linux? В исходниках явным образом указано // +build windows - поэтому если вы собираете в Linux, вам компилятор правильно пишет `build constraints exclude all Go files. Нужно собирать в Windows.

Судя по скриншотам, вы работаете в Линуксе. Библиотека github.com/lxn/walk предназначена исключительно для Windows, во всех исходниках стоит тег сборки
// +build windows

то есть файл включается в сборку только если выставлен тег windows.
Вам нужно собирать приложение Windows:
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build

Я проверил с приложением из README - собирает EXE файл. Запустить, разуемеется, не получается, так как это виндовый исполнимый файл ))
Дабы компилятор в VSCODE не ругался, надо в файл .vscode/settings.json добавить :
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
        "GOOS": "windows",
        "GOARCH": "amd64"
    }

Команда go build -tags windows не сработает, так как по этому тегу подтянутся исходники из стандартной библиотеки, и возникнут кучи конфликтов с дубликатами имён, например
/usr/local/go/src/internal/goos/zgoos_windows.go:7:7: GOOS redeclared in this block
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/goos/zgoos_linux.go:7:7: other declaration of GOOS

Поэтому только GOOS=windows, только кросс-компиляция.

Вообще я пытался хотя бы импортировать его. Не собирал. Хотел попробовать но видимо не судьба
